# HSQLDB Error: unexpected token: FOREIGN

Tags: sql, syntax-error, hsqldb

I have the following SQL I am running in my local HSQLDB 2.3.2 database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries (
    country_id              INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    country_version         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    country_name            NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    country_label           NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    country_description     NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
    country_code            NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT uc_countries UNIQUE (country_id, country_version, country_label, country_description, country_code)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS states (
    state_id                INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    state_version           INTEGER NOT NULL
    state_name              NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    state_label             NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    state_description       NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    country_id              INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(country_id),
    CONSTRAINT uc_states UNIQUE (state_id, state_version, state_label, state_description, country_id)
);
```

When I run this I get:

```
Error: unexpected token: FOREIGN
SQLState:  42581
ErrorCode: -5581
```

What is going on here, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Why the downvote with no explanation? If this is a dupe, please show me the question its a dupe of! Otherwise, this is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), shows effort/research, and contains everything one needs to diagnose/troubleshoot it.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think it's a good question so I upvoted it.

Comment: Do you still get this error if you execute each statement separately? It might be due to the way it complies.

Comment: Thanks @april4181 (+1) - it was just plain oversight on my part (see my comment under the accepted answer). Thanks for taking the time to make these suggestions though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a difference between `INT NOT NULL` and `INTEGER NOT NULL`? Because you have defined the `country_id` fields by both.

Also, if you insert `SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;` at the top, do you still get this error?

Comment: Ughhhhh, I can't believe how long I've been staring at that and have been overlooking it. `INT` is not valid, it has to be `INTEGER`. Bounty and accepted answer rewarded! Thanks!